# While loop only executing once inside of for loop

Tags: c++

Hello all you wonderful people, easy question here,

I have a bit of code here to calculate a best-fit line equation. I'm having trouble with the while loop that's nested in the for loop. Currently, "while(points >> Xi >> Yi)" is only running once, and then (I'm guessing) as it's reached the end of the document, it isn't repeating itself. How can I get it to repeat 1000 times? Can't use arrays, we haven't been taught those in class yet ;(.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double measureSSE(double m, double b, double Xi, double Yi)
{
    return (Yi - ((m * Xi) + b)) * (Yi - ((m * Xi) + b));
}

int main()
{
    double Xi = 0, Yi = 0;
    double m  = 0, b  = 0;
    double dm = 0, db = 0;
    double SSE = 0;

    ifstream points("points.txt");

    if(points.is_open())
    {
        for(int counter = 0; counter < 1000; counter++)
        {
            while(points >> Xi >> Yi)
            {
                dm += -2 * Xi * (Yi - (m * Xi) - b);
                db += -2 *      (Yi - (m * Xi) - b);

                m -= .01 * dm;
                b -= .01 * db;

                SSE += measureSSE(m, b, Xi, Yi);
            }

            cout << "SSE: " << SSE << endl;
        }

        cout << "Final Model: y = " << m << "x + " << b << endl;

        points.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file." << endl;
}
```

Comment: In the first `for` iteration you will enter the `while`, and read all of the file. Following attempts to read will fail because you never reinitialize/recreate the `points` stream.

Comment: IOW, after you exit the `while` loop (because the expression evaluates to `false`), you do not reset the variables so that the expression is `true` again.

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to re-read from the start of the file each time?

Comment: So can I put the " ifstream points("points.txt"); " in the for loop?

Comment: That might be the case. Clarify what you want to do.

Comment: Each of the 1000 times I'm reading through the file, it's supposed to be updating the m and b from y = mx + b closer and closer. So I think I need to initialize it each iteration?

Comment: Just on a side note: Linear regression is usually done with least-squares

Comment: Quite unclear. I've answered anyway but for future readers please clarify your question.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann Thanks, this was simply the way required in the assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to restart the iteration-through-file from scratch each time, you need to [*seek* the read cursor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) before your `while` loop so that it works even when a previous run reached EOF. You'll also need to first clear the EOF flag (unless you're writing C++11 or later, in which this is done for you).

The language doesn't have any special rule to do this for you when you re-enter a `while` loop predicated on extraction from a stream.

```
    for(int counter = 0; counter < 1000; counter++)
    {
        // Clear EOF flag, and revert to the beginning of the stream
        points.clear();
        points.seekg(0);

        // Extract all "points" from the file
        while(points >> Xi >> Yi)
```

I'm not quite sure what `SSE` is supposed to do here as you never actually use its value other than for debug output. I might suggest resetting its value to `0` on each iteration of the `for` loop, if I knew what it did. :)

Comment: I tried those two additions, but it is still only running once.

Comment: Here's the updated code with your suggestions, but still not working: http://pastebin.com/2EY6kR7y as the comment says, the output, from the " cout << "SSE: " line, is every line of the points.txt file but only once

Comment: @LukeFowler: Sorry, the `clear` must come first otherwise the EOF flag prevents the `seekg` from doing anything (on C++03, at least)

Comment: Thank you! That's it. Also, outputting SSE was required in the assignment as a way to "visualize" the error getting lower and lower. Thanks again.

Comment: @LukeFowler: You probably want to reset `SSE` then too